# Issues using current_user on create action (nested attributes)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I want to associate a user model to a resume model. The create action works perfectly without the association between user and resume. In the form I can upload a pdf file with carrierwave and associate it to the resume model (download_file:string).
I want that one user can only have one resume. I have updated the user and resume model:

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :resume, :dependent => :destroy

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

**resume.rb**

```
class Resume < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  mount_uploader :download_file, DownloadFileUploader
end
```

I have run also a migration on add user_id column on the resume model:

**schema.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170822204938) do

  create_table "resumes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "download_file"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

I have updated my resume controller by adding the user_id in the params and I have updated also the create action so the user_id key from the current_user can be passed:

**resumes_controller.rb**

```
 class ResumesController < ApplicationController
  around_filter :catch_not_found
  before_action :find_resume, only: [ :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  
  def show
  end
  
  def new
    @resume = Resume.new
  end

  def create
    @resume = current_user.resume.new(resume_params)
    if @resume.save
      redirect_to @resume
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
  
  def edit
  end
        
  def update
    if @resume.update resume_params
      redirect_to @resume, notice: "Your resume was successfully saved!"
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
  
  def destroy
    @resume.destroy
    redirect_to new_resume_path, notice: "Your resume was successfully deleted!"
  end
  
  private
  
  def resume_params
    params.require(:resume).permit( :user_id, :download_file, :remove_download_file)
  end
  
  def find_resume
    @resume = Resume.find(params[:id])
  end
  
  def catch_not_found
    yield
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    redirect_to(root_url, :notice => 'Record not found')
  end
  
end
```

Unfortunately I'm getting an "undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass" Error:

[image]

I have also dropped, created and migrated the database again but it still does not work.

**What am I missing? How can I make this work?**

If you have further question just let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the error because when you call `current_user.resume` you are calling the relation, which does not exist so it is `nil` so when you then call `new` what is really happening is `nil.new`. If you want to build a new resume object for the current user, you should use the `has_one` relation build method:

```
@resume = current_user.build_resume(resume_params)
```

Answer (score 1):

While this has been iterated a couple of times, the issue is that you're querying a relation that doesn't exist yet.

A couple options would be the use the `[build][1]` method, or you could do something similar to that of

```
def new
  @resume = Resume.new(resume_params)
end

def create
  @resume = current_user.build_resume(resume_params)
  if @resume.save
    ~~~~
  else
    ~~~~
  end
end
```

The reason I'm posting a similar answer is actually to make mention of using the [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) gem to help debug issues like this

By placing the trigger `byebug` in the create/new method you would have been able to freely see what `current_user` `resume`, `@resume` `current_user.resume` etc are resolving too, which in my experience can usually help solve a lot of these issues.

Comment: If I call resume_params on the new action I'm getting an error... the updated create action did for me the trick! Thanks a lot for your suggesstion with byebug! This is truly a game changer I will be able to locate simillar issues much faster! Thank you!

Comment: @trickydiddy No problem - I didn't know about byebug for the first few months of my dev time, and it is absolutely an essential gem. 

And you're right - resume_params would be an issue with your new function - We didn't seem to look.  One thing I would also add if look into strong_params - To ensure you are only injesting what you expect into the DB.

Something like 
    def resume_params
      params.require(:resume).permit(:download_file)
    end

With the current setup I could make a POST with something else to the model.